# logarithm of ideal gas law

Tags: ideal-gas

This question is about taking the logarithm of the ideal gas law. In a fluids text book the author writes:

> First recall a couple of ideal gas relationships involving potential temperature, $\theta$,  and entropy s...

$$\log(\theta) = \log(T) - \dfrac{R}{c_{p}}\log(p) = \dfrac{1}{\gamma}\log(p) - \log(\rho),$$  where $\gamma=\dfrac{c_{p}}{c_{v}}$.

When I take the logarithm of the ideal gas law though I get:

$$\log(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{\gamma}\log(p) - \log(\rho) - \log(R) + \dfrac{R}{c_{p}}\log(p_{0}),$$

where $R$ is the gas constant ($p=\rho{RT}$) and $c_{p}$ is the specific heat constant. Note I have used the relationship $c_{p}-c_{v}=R$. I get the same thing if I take the logarithm of the definition for potential temperature directly. Does anyone know why the author does not have those last two constant terms? Am I doing something wrong?